# How to get table row data in different table when selecting a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I have a table in which some fields are given, like Service, Amount, tax, Action, When click on checkbox I want the all table row data could show on a different table and when I select the other checkbox I want this row data also should add below it in a table.

```
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Service </th>
            <th scope="col">Amount</th>
            <th scope="col">tax</th>
            <th scope="col">Action</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>Subscription Charges</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>500.00</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span >90.00</span>
            </td>
            <td >
                <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="590.00"  /> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>registration fees</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>200.00</span>
            </td>
            <td >
                <span >80.00</span>
            </td>
            <td >
                <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="590.00"  /> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Service </th>
            <th scope="col">Amount</th>
            <th scope="col">tax</th>
            <th scope="col">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>    
</table>
<input type="text" name="tot_amount">
```

Comment: Please provide relevant code that you have tried so far. User Code snippet or JSFiddle to regenerate the issue and share with SO users

Comment: I still do not understand your problem. Please correct me If I am wrong. 
I am considering that there are 2 tables in your view. Table 1 has all the records and Table 2 is result table. When user tick mark any row from table 1, the same row should be added in table 2. Is it correct?

Comment: yes bindi rawat

Comment: @JayArya, What action should be performed on table 2(result table) checkbox's tick-untick event?

Comment: yes i want the all the table row data in second table when i tick on checkbox of this row , when i tick on another table row checkbox i want that table row data in second table , and the first table should be stable

Comment: Bhushan Kawadkar , thank you very much for your precious time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("change",".tot_amount",function(){  
  if (this.checked){  
     var servicetext = $(this).closest("tr").find('td').eq(0).find('span').text();
     var totalamt = $('#tot_amount').val();
     if(totalamt != ''){
     $('#tot_amount').val(totalamt + ", " + servicetext); 
     }
     else{
     $('#tot_amount').val(servicetext);
     }  
     
      var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
      $("#table2 tbody").append("<tr class='servicetr'>" + $tr.html() + "</tr>");
  }  
  else{
   var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");  
   $('#table2').find(".servicetr").each(function(){    
     if($tr.html() == $(this).html())
     $(this).remove();  
   });
  
  }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="table1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tbody>

         <tr>
        <th scope="col">Service </th>
        <th scope="col">Amount</th>
        <th scope="col">tax</th>
        <th scope="col">Action</th>
        </tr>

        <tr class='servicetr'>
                <td class="service">
                <span>Subscription Charges</span>
                 </td>
                 <td>
                <span>500.00</span>
                 </td>
                 <td class="service">
                <span >90.00</span>
                 </td>
                 <td >
              <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="590.00"  /> 
                 </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class='servicetr'>
                <td>
                <span>registration fees</span>
                 </td>
                 <td >
                <span>200.00</span>
                 </td>
                 <td >
                <span >80.00</span>
                 </td>
                 <td >
              <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="590.00"  /> 
                 </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<br/>

<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="table2" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tbody>

         <tr>
        <th scope="col">Service </th>
        <th scope="col">Amount</th>
        <th scope="col">tax</th>
        <th scope="col">Action</th>
        </tr>

    </tbody>    
</table>
<br/>
<input type="text" name="tot_amount" id="tot_amount" style="width:100%;">
```

Comment: @JayArya, Please mark it as answer if you get your solution; otherwise provide further details.

Comment: bindi rawal can u tell me I want the table row service in an input , like registration in an input when i select checkbox

Comment: @JayArya, I do not understand your problem at all. Please elaborate more.

Comment: I want only td1 details like subscription charges and registration in an input when tick on checkbox , if click on table row1  checkbox its td subscription charges should be added in an input and when i select another checkbox its td1 like registration fees should be added with a comma , like subscription charges , registration fees in an input

Comment: @JayArya,  Consider I selected subscription charges and registration fees from table 1, then what should textbox input element display?
Subscription charges, registration fees? 
Or 
590, 280?

Comment: subscription charges and registration fees only in an input when I tick on their's row checkbox

Comment: @JayArya, I have updated above code snippet. Let me know If it is useful.

Comment: Oh this have some error , when i untick it and tick it again the data is been adding in table and in input , also i wanted that input field already should have been present there and then that data be added in that input field , by the way thank u so much for your precious time

Comment: @JayArya, what do you want to perform on untick? Do you want to remove same row from the result table?

Comment: yes i want untick function also , mean tick and untick both ,

Comment: mai ye chahta hu ki ek input box waha pahle se he present ho jisme ye registration aur subscription show ho

Comment: @JayArya, I updated above code snippet for untick event. Up vote my answer if you find it useful.

Comment: ok bindi raval , that is not possible this time because i am not allowed to vote

Answer (score 1):

Try this: You can bind click handlers for checkboxes where remove `TR` along with child elements and push it to another table.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("change",".tot_amount",function(){
      var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
      $("#table2 tbody").append("<tr>" + $tr.html().replace('class="tot_amount"','') + "</tr>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="table1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tbody>

         <tr>
        <th scope="col">Service </th>
        <th scope="col">Amount</th>
        <th scope="col">tax</th>
        <th scope="col">Action</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
                <td>
                <span>Subscription Charges</span>
                 </td>
                 <td >
                <span>500.00</span>
                 </td>
                 <td >
                <span >90.00</span>
                 </td>
                 <td >
              <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="590.00"  /> 
                 </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
                <td>
                <span>registration fees</span>
                 </td>
                 <td >
                <span>200.00</span>
                 </td>
                 <td >
                <span >80.00</span>
                 </td>
                 <td >
              <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="590.00"  /> 
                 </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>



<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="table2" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tbody>

         <tr>
        <th scope="col">Service </th>
        <th scope="col">Amount</th>
        <th scope="col">tax</th>
        <th scope="col">Action</th>
        </tr>

    </tbody>    
</table>
<input type="text" name="tot_amount">
```

Comment: THe snippet is working but i want the first tabe to be stable ,, only the value be added in second table

Comment: @JayArya, In that case you can copy then TR html to create new row in another table instead of append. I have updated my post, please check